How do I change the Rust Analyzer target directory?
The default Rust Analyzer target directory is called target which conflicts with the name used when cargo build is run.
How can I change the target directory from target to some other name?

What is the conflict exactly?

@markus some libraries wrap C libs which themselves need to be built. Sometimes those libraries get triggered for a rebuild by the rust analyzer and by cargo, resulting in repeated rebuilding of something which doesn't need to be rebuilt. I don't fully understand why this happens yet

Go to Rust Analyzer Extension Settings, search for args.

Rust-Analyzer > Cargo: Extra Args

Add the following two values:

--target-dir
target-rust-analyzer


I use --target-dir=target/analyzer - a single param but more importantly uses a subdirectory within target, which is nice since target is already gitignore'd by default and still doesn't conflict with the rest.

This is a much better answer, the rust-analyzer.cargo.targetDir setting is highly opinionated and strictly relative to workspace.

If you use rust-analyzer extension of VS Code, you can specify target directory using extension settings.

Press Ctrl + ,
Write rust-analyzer cargo target dir
It would show options to set setting for User or Workspace. First apply to all projects you open, second only to currently opened project.
You need Rust-analyzer › Cargo: Target Dir setting which is specifically for your use case.
It is possible to set value to either true or some string:

Setting value to "my_some_value" would mean that rust-analyzer files would be stored in my_some_value in workspace root.
Setting it to boolean value true would make rust-analyzer store files in target/rust-analyzer which is a good default. I myself use it.



My VS Code settings.json:
{
  "rust-analyzer.cargo.targetDir": true
}

You probably should to keep rust-analyzer files inside target directory like me because this is supported better by tooling:

Entire target directory is ignored by default template of .gitignore/.hgignore created by cargo new so you don't need to add rust-analyzer output directory manually.
cargo clean would clean both normal cargo output and rust-analyzer output which is often good. Also, cargo clean almost never conflicts with rust-analyzer in my experience.


@kmdreko Yeah, you are right! I had specified this setting 2 times, first as true, second times as path so it actually used true but I thought that it used my string. Would update the answer.

Interesting idea to put the location as a subdirectory. I like that idea. I guess you just have to ensure the directory name isn't something used by cargo itself to avoid a conflict. In this case with this example it would be surprising if a current or future version of cargo used the name you've shown in this example. Sorry for pointing out the obvious here just thought it might be worth mentioning
